# TextView size in dp when wrap_content

Tags: android

I'm creating a widget for which I need to calculate the `minHeight` and `minWidth`.

Now if I have a `TextView` which has a width and height of `wrap_content`, and a text size of `18sp`, how can I find out what size the `TextView` will become in `dp`?

Comment: you cant get `dp` size, only in `px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView tv;
int tvWidth = tv.getWidth();
int tvHeight = tv.getHeight();

float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float densityWidth = tvWidth / density;
float densityHeight = tvHeight / density;
```

If I right understand, its for you.